# Abort if none of previous tasks were run

Tags: ansible

I have a `tasks.yml` that contains something like :

```
- name: something on Debian wheezy
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and ansible_distribution_version == '7'

- name: something on Debian jessie
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and ansible_distribution_version == '8'

- name: something on Ubuntu
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

I want to add a task (or something) that aborts the playbook if none of those tasks were run.

Maybe "something" is installing a package, and some tasks that come after are configuring that newly installed package. If I run the playbook on a RedHat system, that package won't be installed, and I want to abort before executing the tasks that configure it.

I think I could do something like:

```
- fail: msg="abort!"
  when: not (ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and ansible_distribution_version == '7') and not (ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and ansible_distribution_version == '8') and not ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

... but that's annoying. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Are you sure this is a good playbook design? I'd prefer to fail in the beginning of playbook execution if the OS is not supported, or If it doesn't matter just skip the unnecessary tasks.

Comment: Right, that may be better to fail early, but that means checking for supported OS in two quite far-apart places, I'm not fond of that either. I'd rather fail there and know that this is why that particular OS is not supported, and then add the code to install `something` for that OS and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: Install pkg
    debug: msg="Installed pkg"
    when: "{{ ansible_distribution == 'Debian' }}"
    register: debian_pkg

  - name: Install pkg
    debug: msg="Installed pkg"
    when: "{{ ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu' }}"
    register: ubuntu_pkg

  - fail: msg="Unsupported OS"
    when: "debian_pkg|skipped and ubuntu_pkg|skipped"
```

Comment: `pkg_installed` in this example is registered in every task – so it will trigger fail task if Debian task is done and Ubuntu task is skipped.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I've just realized that. Already fixed the snippet.

Comment: Yeah, good. But I'll leave my comment for people thinking why there are different registered variables and not the same one :)

Comment: I thought about registering a variable but I (correctly, it seems) had the impression that I would require as many as tasks, and not a single one. That helps a bit, but it's still a bit verbose to my liking. I finally went another way, I'll describe it in another answer, but I'll mark this as the accepted answer since it does answer the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally went a simpler, more "business"-accurate way. I want to install `something`, and I then expect `something` to be installed. In fact, in my infrastructure where not everything is automated (I'm not root everywhere) I sometimes can't install `something`, but I still want to check that it is installed (it was installed out-of-band).

So, after the tasks that install `something` depending on the OS, I added a task that checks if it is installed, simply by trying to run it. Something like that:

```
- include: install_something.yml # contains the install tasks for each OS
  when: can_become_root

- name: Check that something is installed
  command: something --version
```